# display "value" on edit text matlab

Tags: user-interface, matlab

Hello I'm creating a GUI and I want the "Edit text" button to display the name of the file I selected....i've stored the filename and the pathname in a variable called "File_Selected:....but how do i pass the filename only to the EditText function on my GUI

Comment: @Tim: A small advice: You opened 7 questions, but yet didn't accept answer for any of them. Please do, this will increase your chance to get more answers for other questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Find the tag of the button (or text field) by double-clicking on the button in GUIDE and looking at the `Tag`-propert. Assume the tag is called `edit2`.

Then, inside a callback (which has three input arguments, `hObject`, `eventdata`, and `handles`), you write

```
set(handles.edit2,'String',File_Selected)
```